# Linux message to all terminals

Tags: linux

When I'm trying to send some message to all terminals through `echo "some message" > /dev/pts/*` it works good. But when I do the same thing through bash script then error occurrs: `myscript.sh: line 2: /dev/pts/*: Permission denied`. Even when I set highest privileges to `myscript.sh`. What can I do to make it work?

```
read msg
echo $msg > /dev/pts/*
```

Comment: Do you interpret the file with bash or sh? Whichever shell it is, it doesn't expand the glob, it seems. Use the same shell for running the script that you use in your interactive session.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you have a look at the wall command?

See http://linux.die.net/man/1/wall

You need privileges to do this, but here is described a workaround

[How do I broadcast messages to all bash terminal in python using wall command with stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25282661/how-do-i-broadcast-messages-to-all-bash-terminal-in-python-using-wall-command-wi)

Comment: Why? What error do you get? Look at your path, it should exist in /usr/sbin, as it is an admin tool

Comment: Ok, for your particular question, you can also try: source <script> and remove the header (#!/bin/bash). That should be equivalent to typing in your current shell. It's strange that something that runs on the shell doesn't work in a script, but sometimes interactive programs behave different (for example telnet does not accept the password when run non-interactively).

Comment: Nothing appears in any terminal when I type `wall -n <some message>` and no error is there. I type it as root of course.

Comment: For the wall side, as root you can enable by setting `mesg y` in /etc/profile, so it becomes the default for all users. For the script, I am not sure why it behaves in a different way, please share the results when running like `source myscript.sh`, both with and without the shell line (#!/bin/sh or #!/bin/bash)

Comment: When I'm trying add `#!/bin/bash` or `#!/bin/sh` to `myscript.sh` then other error occurrs: `myscript.sh: line 3: /dev/pts/*: ambiguous redirect`. With `source myscript.sh` is error: `myscript.sh:3: permission denied: /dev/pts/ptmx
`

Comment: For the wall, the argument is a file name not a message

Comment: Try using a loop, e.g. `for j in /dev/pts/*  do; echo $mesg > $j; done`